# Copy images in folder from one domain to another

Tags: php

It is possible to copy all images from a domain to another. I have access to both domains but there are thousands of pictures. I figure it would be easier to execute a php script once every minute to transfer 1000 at a time.

Thanks for any help/guidance

Comment: Any reason why you can't tar/zip up the images and then scp from server to the other?

Comment: I feel this was closed unjustly, but anyway, you now  have time to refine your question and ask it again :D Please tell us what kind of access you have to the servers: SSH? SCP? FTP? Can you use Cron jobs? Please add much more detail so people can answer the question directly without having to make shots in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tar/gzip it up and then scp/sftp once.